# in javascript, if condtion is returng false?

Tags: javascript

below is the code,

```
if(3.0+0.1 == 3.1){
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it is returning false.

Comment: if(3.0+0.1 == 3.1){
console.log(true);
}
else{
console.log(false);
}

Answer (score 0):

This is because `3.0+1` makes the following equation: `3.0 + 1.0 === 3.1`
which isn't true try `3.0 + 0.1 === 3.1` or a more safer option *(due to how floats work)*
 `(30 + 1) / 10 === 3.1`